# How to Get Grape Jelly Flavor in Porter?

Tags: yeast, all-grain, flavor, porter

Brewed an All Grain Peanut Butter Porter using Pb2 and I am looking to get some grape jelly flavor in there.

I used east Kent Goldings at 60, and that was it with a Belgian Ale yeast.

Couldn't find much from Jack's Abbey or Funky Buddha on their process.  What I did find is that *sometimes* English Ale yeast can bring out a fruity component.

Any tips from the masters?

Comment: "Grape jelly" flavor is "concord grape." A sulfite-free grape juice concentrate (eg, Welch's) would probably do the trick. I'm leaving this as a comment, as I'm not too familiar with brewing beer, so I can't really help beyond making a suggestion.

Comment: Are you talking about this batch or a revision? This batch I think you're limited to an adjunct. Next batch you could manipulate a yeast to produce the fruit esters. Esters are controlled by temp and pitch amount.

Comment: ahhhh...good question.  I am talking about a revision.  The original never meant to have a "jelly" flavor.  So I guess the next question is:  How do I manipulate the yeast?

Answer (score 1):

For a second batch you can try ester enhancement, but I don't know of a yeast that will give this ester in the amount you want without it being clouded with other esters and phenols.

He'Brew Rejewvenator actually brews with concord and merlot grapes. There are many answers here how to do fruit additions

What I would try actually is a post fermenation flavor addition on the porter you have now. Reduce some Manischewitz concord grape wine in a pot to the consistency of hot syrup. Using a beaker and pipet (or measuring cup and spoons) make additions of the reduction to small sample like 200ml. If you get the flavor you like then you scale the addition up to the full keg volume. You will need a preservative or cold storage to prevent secondary fermentation of the new sugars.

Hope this helps.